# KDTree duplicating rows

Tags: python, pandas, kdtree

I have two dataframes.

1. The first dataframe (`map`) consists of two columns: "X" and "Y". `map` is 83150 rows.
2. The second data frame (`cords`) consists of two columns: "X Rotate" and "Y Rotate". `coords` is 2702 rows.

The objective is to find the nearest neighbor for each (X,Y) coordinate within `map` to the (X Rotate, Y Rotate) coordinates within `coords`.

In order to do this, I duplicate each row within `coords` 31 times because of 83150/2702. Now, `coords` has 83762 rows. This means each (X,Y) coordinate will find its nearest neighbor to the (X Rotate, Y Rotate) and there will be 612 coordinates within `coords` that will not have a nearest neighbor match.

This is the function to make this happen:

```
def nearest_neighbors(df, map):
    num_pts = math.ceil(map.shape[0] / df.shape[0])
    map = map[["X", "Y"]].to_numpy()
    duplicate_cords_df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, num_pts, axis=0), columns=df.columns)
    duplicate_cords_sub = duplicate_cords_df[["X Rotate", "Y Rotate"]].to_numpy()
    duplicate_cords_sub = duplicate_cords_sub.to_numpy()
    list_of_dicts = []
    for row in map:
        map_tree = spatial.cKDTree(duplicate_cords_sub)
        distance, index = map_tree.query(row)
        cols = ["Map X", "Map Y", "X Rotate", "Y Rotate", "Distance"]
        map_x = row[0]
        map_y = row[1]
        coords_x = (duplicate_cords_sub[index]).flat[0]
        coords_y = (duplicate_cords_sub[index]).flat[1]
        results = [map_x, map_y, coords_x, coords_y, distance]
        results_dict = dict(zip(cols, results))
        list_of_dicts.append(results_dict)
    results_df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)
    return results_df
```

However, when I check the count for the number of duplicates in `results_df`, I notice that each (X Rotate, Y Rotate) coordinate is being used a varying number of times.

```
overall_df_dup = results_df.groupby(['X Rotate', 'Y Rotate']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print(overall_df_dup)

                X Rotate           Y Rotate   count
0                -74.25               0.00     16
1                -72.48             -12.37     28
2                -72.48              -8.84     37
3                -72.48              -5.30     43
4                -72.48              -1.77     39
...                 ...                ...    ...
2697              70.71              14.14     62
2698              72.48              -8.84     45
2699              72.48              -1.77     55
2700              72.48               1.77     47
2701              72.48               5.30     48
```

I checked the duplicates count of the data frame given to the  KDTree function and it was correct:

```
coords_dup = duplicate_cords.groupby(['X Rotate', 'Y Rotate']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print(coords_dup)

                 X Rotate           Y Rotate  count
0                -74.25              -0.00     31
1                -72.48             -12.37     31
2                -72.48              -8.84     31
3                -72.48              -5.30     31
4                -72.48              -1.77     31
...                 ...                ...    ...
2697              70.71              14.14     31
2698              72.48              -8.84     31
2699              72.48              -1.77     31
2700              72.48               1.77     31
2701              72.48               5.30     31
```

**How does the resulting df contain more duplicates of the coordinates than existing in the original data frame fed into the KdTree function?**

Bonus question: Is it possible to have each (X Rotate, Y Rotate) coordinate be mapped to 30 times and only some (X Rotate, Y Rotate) be mapped to 31 times? Ideally, I want each (X Rotate, Y Rotate) coordinate to be mapped to 30 times regardless.

Comment: Why do you duplicate rows on `coords` dataframe?

Comment: The length of the `map` dataframe is ~31 times longer than the `coords` dataframe. So I duplicate the rows within `coords` 31 times so each coordinate pair in `map` can map to a nearest neighbor coordinate pair within `coords`.

Comment: If I am going about this duplication process incorrectly then I can change my approach. It is just what made sense to do in my head.

Comment: I am hoping to have each (X Rotate, Y Rotate) coordinate be mapped to 30 times and only some (X Rotate, Y Rotate) be mapped to 31 times. Ideally, I want each (X Rotate, Y Rotate) coordinate to be mapped to 30 times regardless. That's why I was thinking of duplicating `coords` 31 times.

Comment: (X Rotate1, Y Rotate1) will always match the same (X, Y), no?

Comment: What do you mean by this question? There are 83150 (X,Y) unique coordinates within `map` and 2702 (X Rotate, Y Rotate) unique coordinates within `coords`. All 83150 coordinates have to find a nearest neighbor match within the 2702 coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the right answer in first intention however this can help using `KDTree`

Create a minimal reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

gen_coords = lambda s: np.round(np.random.randint(-100, 100, s) \
                                + np.random.random(s), 2)

df_map = pd.DataFrame(gen_coords((83150, 2)), columns=['X', 'Y'])
df_coords = pd.DataFrame(gen_coords((2702, 2)), columns=['X Rotate', 'Y Rotate'])
```

Map coordinates:

```
df_coords['IDX'] = cKDTree(df_map).query(df_coords, k=30)[1].tolist()
df_coords = df_coords.explode('IDX')
df_coords[['X', 'Y']] = df_map.loc[df_coords['IDX'].tolist()].values
df_coords = df_coords.drop(columns='IDX')
```

Output result:

```
>>> df_coords

      X Rotate  Y Rotate      X      Y
0        99.00     57.35  99.18  57.13
0        99.00     57.35  98.54  57.53
0        99.00     57.35  99.14  58.20
0        99.00     57.35  99.88  57.36
0        99.00     57.35  98.03  56.94
...        ...       ...    ...    ...
2701     92.75     -8.69  91.40  -9.74
2701     92.75     -8.69  91.75  -7.29
2701     92.75     -8.69  93.41  -7.09
2701     92.75     -8.69  94.48  -8.78
2701     92.75     -8.69  93.29 -10.36

[81060 rows x 4 columns]

>>> df_coords.value_counts(['X Rotate', 'Y Rotate'])
X Rotate  Y Rotate
-99.71    -20.20      30
 35.72     85.56      30
 34.64     76.37      30
 34.76     8.32       30
 34.90    -4.75       30
                      ..
-32.69    -44.76      30
-32.66     72.96      30
-32.63    -40.65      30
-32.61     34.91      30
 99.89     98.02      30
Length: 2702, dtype: int64
```